# Wordpress search returns 404 from pages?

Tags: wordpress

When i search from root or shop page something, fox example "food" it returns normally results with url

> site.com?s=food

or from shop:

> site.com/shop/?s=food

, but when i search it from contact or some other page, i get 404 and url:

> site.com/contact/?s=food

I want in second case to redirect to root as first, so when somebody search from contact page, i want

> site.com?s=food

This is some custom template, so default search maybe not work well.

Comment: It looks like you search hasn't been implemented properly - it should always be sending search results to the root page. Show your search form template file.

Comment: @Shiv 
Problem is that i don't have access to files now. Inside searchform.php and product-searchform.php was defined inside action home_url('/').

Comment: If you think it's inside functions.php then you've got bigger problems - Hire someone who knows what they're doing preferably.

Comment: @Shiv I am php developer. And i now have task to fix that bug who someone made :S

Comment: #ShouldHaveMadeItYourself Have fun! If you can show your functions.php and other files and it isn't too long I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

In your search form you need the action attribute of the form element to be set to the home URL. Something similar to this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
```

You could also look at the code reference for get_search_form().
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/

Comment: This custom theme has searchform.php and product-searchform.php, i think that second is defined as primary because when i change something  inside product-searchform.php that has effect to my search design. But, when i change action to something like www.google.com, it loads again /contact/?s=x. It looks like somewhere inside functions.php or somewhere else is defined redirection after search? When i try to add my own redirect it say ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: product-searchform.php is typically used by WooCommerce. Removing this file from your theme would allow Woocommerce to revert back to the default version of the file which may be useful for your testing. It's tough to suggest why your site is behaving the way you describe without being able to see the code. The WooCommerce search is included in the template using woocommerce_product_search(): https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/api/

Comment: @Nell Thank you, i will check it tomorrow.